# Python-Mysql NameError: global name 'save_to_db' is not defined

Tags: python, mysql, mqtt, mosquitto

i tried to write python script mqtt that is subscribing data from Mosquitto broker to get all messages from sensors that are publishing data in a specific topic and send data to mysqlDB in order save data

the code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import MySQLdb

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
        save_to_db(msg)
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("192.168.0.132", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()

testdb = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","testdb" )

def save_to_db(msg):
    with testdb:
        cursor = testdb.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pulses (pulse) VALUES (%s)", (msg.payload))
        except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            print('excepttion BD ' + e)
            return None
```

but error will show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sub3.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1378, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 897, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1177, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1766, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2239, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2414, in _handle_publish
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2574, in _handle_on_message
    self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "sub3.py", line 10, in on_message
    save_to_db(msg)
NameError: global name 'save_to_db' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start the loop too early:

```
client.loop_forever()
```

Any code defined *after* this line has not yet executed, so any function objects are not defined yet.

Move that line down to *below* any functions you need to exist when the loop runs.

Comment: `File "sub3.py", line 29, in <module>
    client.loop_forever()`

Comment: @IstabraqMahmood: did the exception *change*, or is it still otherwise exactly the same? Does `print(save_to_db)` just before the `client.loop_forever()` line produce output?

Comment: i have updated my code with new error i put `client.loop_forever()` at the end of the code

Comment: Is there any tutorial using python to Mysql using MQTT ?

Comment: @IstabraqMahmood: that's a **new** error, one that you could either ask a new question about, or find ready solutions to on Stack Overflow (I rolled back the edit). But you are missing a comma after `msg.payload`: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pulses (pulse) VALUES (%s)", (msg.payload,))`; without the comma, there is no tuple there.